# Read drop down selected value in javascript and rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

i'm using rails 2.3.2.
i was try to rails drop down selection. then again use selected drop down value in another select drop down in same page using java script , rails controller and model class.
i want to get "floor_id" value. but i didn't get "floor_id" value in rails view.how can i get "floor_id" value in view page?

i put my modified code below.

rails view code

```
<td>
<%= f.select(:floor_id, ProjectFloor.find(:all,:order => "name ASC",:conditions => ["project_id = ?", @project.id]).collect{|b|[b.name, b.id]}, {:include_blank => 'Select'},{:onchange => "select_floor_id(this.value);"}) %>
</td>

<td>
<%= f.select(:unit_id, @floor.collect{|b|[b.name, b.id]}, {:include_blank => 'Select'}) %>
</td>
```

model class

```
def self.select_units(project_id,floor_id)

    self.find_by_sql(["SELECT distinct project_floor_units.* FROM `project_floor_units`
            INNER JOIN project_floors ON project_floors.id = project_floor_units.project_floor_id
            lEFT JOIN proposed_customers ON proposed_customers.unit_id = project_floor_units.id
            lEFT JOIN project_customers ON project_customers.project_floor_unit_id = project_floor_units.id
            WHERE project_floors.project_id = ? AND  project_floor_units.project_floor_id = ? AND
            proposed_customers.id IS NULL AND project_customers.id IS NULL
            GROUP BY project_floor_units.name ORDER BY project_floor_units.name ASC", project_id, floor_id])
  end
```

controller

```
def new
    @floor_id = params[:floor_id]
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @proposed_customer = ProposedCustomer.new
    @floor = ProjectFloorUnit.select_units(@project.id, @floor_id)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.js # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @proposed_customer }
    end
  end
```

java script code here

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function select_floor_id(floor_id) {
     alert(floor_id);
     jQuery.ajax({
      url: "/proposed_customers/new",
       type: "GET",
       dataType: "json",
       data: {"floor_id" : floor_id},
       success:function(data){

       }
     });
   }

</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you writing your SQL query inside your view?

Comment: yes.i'm writing SQL query inside of my  view